# How to properly delete a row referenced in as a forigen key in JPA (Java, Spring, Hibernate and Postgres)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This issue should be pretty common, but I can't find anything about it. There's a Spring application in which we have `departments` and `employees` tables (on Postgres, if that matters), each employee has a non-null `department_id` (FK to `departments` without any `on delete`) and each department has a nullable `manager_id` (FK to `employees` without any `on delete`). Now I'm trying to delete an employee who is a manager of her own department. So what I do is (JPA):

```java
@Entity
public class Department {
  @Id Integer id;
  @Column Integer managerId;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id Integer id;
  @Column @NotNull Integer departmentId;
}

@Transactional
public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
  val employee = employeeRepository.getById(employeeId);
  val department = departmentRepository.getById(employee.getDepartmentId());
  if (employeeId.equals(department.getManagerId())) {
    department.setManagerId(null);
    departmentRepository.save(department);
  }
  employeeRepository.delete(employee);
}
```

But the transaction fails complaining about the fact that employee is referenced in `departments`. (If I unset `manager_id` column in a new transaction the operation succeeds, obviously). When I checked debug logs, I see that Hibernate executes "delete employee" query first. How can I force JPA/Hibernate to run queries in the right order? Or what's the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this enough?

```
@Transactional
public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId) {
    val employee = employeeRepository.getById(employeeId);
    employeeRepository.delete(employee);
}
```

Comment: You need to unset the manager ID, otherwise you can't delete the record due to FK constraint.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part it was a manager. You're using SpringData, right? Maybe representing a bit better the relationship with JPA would start helping. Otherwise you should set the manager of the department to null (if that actually makes sense), merge (save in SpringData?) the department then flush and finally delete the employee